# Exporting/Importing projects from Netbeans 18 on a laptop to Netbeans 18 on another computer

Tags: php, import, netbeans, export, project

I have about 20 projects in Netbeans 18 on a notebook. Now I want to keep these projects and save them, so I can import them to a new computer. How do I proceed?

I have already transferred the projects (php and html-files) to xampp to the new computer.

I have seen that there is a possibility to export, but only one project, not my about 20 projects. How can I export all of my projects?

Answer (score 0):

Look in the project directory, if there is a `nbproject` directory there, you can simply copy the whole project directory. The project settings should be automatically picked up when you open the project on another computer.